# A TV movie about a boy from modern era entering a portal into an earlier era (like late 1800s)

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a (TV) movie about a boy from modern era who entered a portal (might have been a mirror, or at least I think it was indoors) and got into an earlier era (like late 1800s). There he spent some time and fell in love with a girl. In the end he returned to his time and the portal closed leaving them both separated forever.

I might have seen it sometime around the year 1998 - 2003 (could be outside that but this is probable) and it might have been on a channel like Hallmark or HBO. And since I understood it it must have been dubbed into Czech too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [*Tom's Midnight Garden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom%27s_Midnight_Garden_(film)) (1999) based on a 1958 novel. It has been [filmed several times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom%27s_Midnight_Garden#Film,_TV_or_theatrical_adaptations).

> When Tom Long's brother Peter gets measles he is sent to stay with his Uncle Alan and Aunt Gwen in a flat with no garden. An elderly and reclusive landlady, Mrs Bartholomew, lives upstairs. Because he may be infectious he is not allowed out to play, and feels lonely. Without exercise he is less sleepy at night and when he hears the communal grandfather clock strangely strike 13, he investigates and finds the small back yard is now a large sunlit garden. Here he meets another lonely child called Hatty, who seems to be the only one who can see him. They have adventures which he gradually realises are taking place in the 19th century. Each night when Tom visits, Hatty is slightly older and Tom begins to wonder about the nature of time and reality. In an attempt to discover what's going on Tom asks Hattie to leave her skates in a hidden place. When he goes back into the future he manages to find them. One night Hatty and Tom go out skating however Hatty begins to fall in love with a boy from her own time named Barty and Tom finds he is invisible to her. The next night Tom is unable to find the garden, running into rubbish bins from the modern day instead. Just before Tom returns home he meets Mrs Bartholomew, who is revealed to be the elderly Hatty.

Comment: Wonderful, sounds like that might be it! I have to get it and watch it now and then I accept.

Comment: Cannot find it anywhere... Hope to find it later on... I accept your answer as correct.